# Find inverse of polynomial function

Tags: functions, inverse

Do you know how I could compute the inverse function of the following polynomial?

$f(x) = x^5+x^3+x$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha only gives numerical approximate solutions for $f(x)=2$, so there is probably no formula for the inverse of $f$, though I haven't checked that the Galois group of $f$ is not solvable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function *probably* won't have a nice inverse, since finding the inverse is equivalent to solving the equation $f(x)=c$, or equivalently finding the roots of the equation $x^5+x^3+x-c=0$.  This is a quintic polynomial, and as such probably will likely not have a general solution (i.e. for all $c$) in terms of radicals.  The best you can do is usually some kind of numerical method.

Comment: It is not true that all quintics are unsolvable by radicals. This one might be.

Comment: that's what I see, thanks.

Comment: Well, you would have to show every polynomial in the family $x^5+x^3+x-c$ is solvable.  This sounds more difficult than showing a single polynomial isn't solvable (I'm not a Galois theory expert though)

Comment: Yes. But my point is that the Abel–Ruffini theorem applies only to the *general* quintic, and the one in question is not general.

Comment: In fact, this *is* solvable by radicals, since $f(x)=x(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$. The roots are $x=0,\pm((1\pm\sqrt{3}i)/2)$.

Comment: We're not looking for the roots of $f(x)$, we're looking for the *inverse* of $f$, so roots of $f(x)-c$.